# Forward current message as attachment then delete original message

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I get a lot of spam messages on my work Outlook 2010 account.  I am provided with our spam blocker address to forward the spam (as an attachment) to.

I'd like to click on an icon on the ribbon (I already have this) and have VBA code run that takes the current message, attaches it to a new message, adds an address to the new message, sends the new message and then deletes the original message.  (Deleting can be either putting the message in the "Deleted Items" folder or permanently deleting it.)

**SOLVED!!!!**

Here is code that does exactly what I want.  I found it on the net and modified it to meet my needs.

```
Sub ForwardAndDeleteSpam()
'
' Takes currently highlighted e-mail, sends it as an attachment to
' spamfilter and then deletes the message.
'

    Set objItem = GetCurrentItem()
    Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With objMsg
        .Attachments.Add objItem, olEmbeddeditem
        .Subject = "SPAM"
        .To = "spamfilter@schools.nyc.gov"
        .Send
    End With
    objItem.Delete

    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objMsg = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(Application.ActiveWindow)
    Case "Explorer"
        Set GetCurrentItem = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    Case "Inspector"
        Set GetCurrentItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Case Else
        ' anything else will result in an error, which is
        ' why we have the error handler above
    End Select

    Set objApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Do you think you could show us some code?

Comment: Thank you! I use this to send spam to Spamcop from Outlook. It's crazy that Outlook does not have a Macro recorder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to go through a selection of emails, rather than just one by adapting the code as follows

```
Sub ForwardSpamToNetworkBox()

On Error Resume Next

Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem

If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
   MsgBox ("No item selected")
   Exit Sub
End If

For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With objMsg
        .Attachments.Add objItem, olEmbeddeditem
        .Subject = "SPAM"
        .To = "spam@host.co.uk"
        .Send
    End With
objItem.Delete
Next

Set objItem = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing

End Sub
```

This was created with info from http://jmerrell.com/2011/05/21/outlook-macros-move-email

Ideally, instead of deleting, I'd move it to a subfolder called "Submitted" but I can't get that to work in Public Folders